# How to not show the null character while inserting a character into a 2d string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I was making a pretty simple Battleship game for my school project (I HAVE to use Turbo C++) and i ran into a problem. I'm basically using a 5x5 2D string as my board and hiding a "ship" in it. What I'm trying to do is that whenever the user makes a wrong guess, I want to replace the "O" in the board with an "X", but when i do that, the "O" in the next block gets replaced by a "/0" and shows as a blank space in the output. How do I fix that?

Here's the code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
//A function to initialize the board
void start_board(char a[5][5])
{
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
     {  strcpy(&a[i][j],"O");
     }
     }
}
//A function to display the board
void display_board(char a[5][5])
{  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
     {  cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
     }
}
class board
{   public:
     char board[5][5];
     void start()
     {  start_board(board);
     }
     void display()
     {  display_board(board);
     }
};
class ship
{   public:
    int ship_row, ship_col;
    ship()//CONSTRUCTOR FOR PUTTING COORDINATES OF SHIP
    {  randomize();
       ship_row= random(5);
       ship_col=random(5);
       cout<<ship_row<<endl<<ship_col;

    }
};
class guess: public board, public ship
{  public:
   int guess_row,guess_col;
   char vboard[5][5];
   guess()
   {  start_board(vboard);
   }
   void takeguess();

};
  void guess:: takeguess()
   { int count=0;
     while(count<3)
     {
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"Guess a row ";
   cin>>guess_row;
   cout<<"Guess a column ";
   cin>>guess_col;
   if(guess_row==ship_row && guess_col==ship_col)
   {  cout<<"Congratulations! You sank the battleship!";
      break;
   }
   else if(guess_row>4 || guess_col>4)
   {  cout<<"invalid guess";
   }
   else
   {  clrscr();
      cout<<"Incorrect Guess!"<<endl;
      strcpy(&vboard[guess_row][guess_col],"X");
      display_board(vboard);
      count+=1;
   }
    if(count==3)
    {  cout<<"GAME OVER!";
    }
   }
   }
void main()
{  clrscr();
   board b;
   b.start();
   b.display();
   guess g;
   g.takeguess();
   getch();
}
```

For example, If the user guesses 0,2, and that isn't the ship's location the output will show:

```
OOX O
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
```

Sorry for the messy code(it isn't complete) and any mistakes i made while writing this post, it's my first time using stackoverflow. Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `strcpy`!! You're not copying a string, you're setting the value of a single character in the string, so use the right tool for the job.

```
vboard[guess_row][guess_col] = 'X';
```

This is because "X" is actual 2 characters 'X' and '\0' so your `strcpy` hits 2 cells in your array